# multiple conditions to subset dataframe based on related id

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe called `df` that has an `id` column and a `related_id` column. If the related_id is not null that means there is a desktop version and a mobile version.
I want to subset this dataset to keep only desktop instances if there is a related id. There are also situations however where there can be a mobile observation which has a related id which is also a mobile observation (ids 7 and 8 are examples). In this case i want to keep just one of those observations.

input:

```
id related_id type
1e  2e          desktop
2e  1e          mobile
3x  NaN        desktop
4w  6w          desktop
5m  NaN        mobile
6w  4w          mobile
7q  8q          mobile
8q  7q          mobile
```

output:

```
id related_id type
1e  2e          desktop
3x  NaN        desktop
4w  6w          desktop
5m  NaN        mobile
7q  8q          mobile
```

how can i do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You can `np.sort` the `id` and `related_id` on `axis=1` and create a helper series for grouping, then calculate the `idxmin` with a helper dictionary for the weights:

```
s = pd.Series(map(tuple,np.sort(df[['id','related_id']].fillna(''),axis=1)))
d= {'desktop':1,'mobile':2}
out = df.loc[df['type'].map(d).groupby(s,sort=False).idxmin()]
```

---

```
print(out)

   id related_id     type
0  1e         2e  desktop
2  3x        NaN  desktop
3  4w         6w  desktop
4  5m        NaN   mobile
6  7q         8q   mobile
```

Comment: I just edited my question to update the Ids.Some of the ids are actually characters and not integers